# Can't reach database server at `postgres`:`5432`

Tags: postgresql, docker, nest, prisma, migrate

Trying to dockerize, nests, and Prisma.
Nest is responding correctly to curl requests and and I   can connect to the Postgres server fine with this command

--- docker compose exec postgres psql -h localhost -U postgres -d webapp_dev

Everything works until i   try to run

```
npx prisma migrate dev --name init
```

then i   get back

```
Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `postgres`:`5432`
```

Here is my code:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
  backend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 9229:9229 # debugger port
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: yarn start:debug
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres@postgres/webapp_dev
      PORT: 8000
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: webapp_dev
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
```

**DockerFile**

```
FROM node:16

# Create app directory, this is in our container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# Need to copy both package and lock to work
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install

COPY prisma/schema.prisma ./prisma/
RUN npx prisma generate

# Bundle app source
COPY . .


RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node": "dist/main"]
```

**.env**

```
//.env 
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres@postgres/webapp_dev
```

Comment: Not too hot at docker, so feel free to blast me. I   am just stuck in google purgatory atm

Comment: If you run your `npx prisma migrate` command as part of your build (I can't see it in the files you've posted), then Postgres isn't available at that time. Postgres is only available at run-time.

Comment: I  am running it in the terminal after I  have already started docker containers

Comment: I  figured it out. Changing ```DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres@postgres/webapp_dev``` to   
```DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres@localhost/webapp_dev``` 
in the .env file worked for me

Comment: My whole team are still having issues with this. Totally unable to get the the root cause of the problem. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I would suggest that if you get it working, don't rebuild your db or docker images. This issue is pesky and intermittent.

Comment: It's something related to timeouts. Adding &connect_timeout=300 after ?schema=public fixed the same issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error I solved it after adding `?connect_timeout=300` at my DATABASE_URL

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this is the only issue but your db url does not contain the db secret in it

```bash
DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:mysecret@postgres/webapp_dev?schema=public
```

Comment: I just added "?schema=public" and it works fine. The database hosting did not include this one upon copy.